# How to convert a nested array to a multidimensional array in Julia

Tags: arrays, julia

I want to make `Array{UInt8,3}` (color image data) from `Array{UInt8,2}` (grayscale image data) in Julia 0.4 like the following:

```
using Images
dat = data(img)
dat2 = map(x -> (v = x*2 % UInt8; [v,0,0]), dat)
img2 = colorim(dat2)
```

However, the code above makes `Array{Array{UInt8,1},2}` instead. How can I make a "flatten" multidimensional array?

Answer (score 4):

You can also use

```
z = zeros(UInt8, size(A))
colorim(cat(3, A, z, z))
```

where `A` is whatever you want in the red channel.

Answer (score 2):

Using array comprehension:

```
dat2 = UInt8[k==1 ? (dat[i,j]*2)%UInt8 : zero(UInt8)
             for i=1:size(dat,1),j=1:size(dat,2),k=1:3]
```

Answer (score 2):

Another approach could be:

```
dat2=zeros(UInt8,(size(dat)...,3))
dat2[:,:,1]=2*dat1
```